# Like using leading wildcard Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have street names only and I am trying to search all addresses in the database that contain the street name. For example, I have `Mojave Rd`, and the database value may be `123 Mojave Rd Las Vegas`. This forces me to use a leading and ending wildcard. I am trying to run the following query for hundreds of street names. The execution plan looks good but the query constantly times out. How do I optimize this

```
SELECT
  full_address,
  city,
  state,
  zip
FROM
  address_table
WHERE
  full_address LIKE '%MOJAVE RD%'
AND 
  state IN ('NV');
```

Comment: Hundreds shouldn't be a problem especially if state is indexed. Please post explain plan.

Comment: What do you mean it "times out"? I've run queries that took several hours to complete and never "timed out". Check your database parameters maybe... Apart from that I think that you are negating any positive effect an index might have by having the wildcard at the beginning of the string (afaik the further it is to the right, the better an index can be used). PS: establishing atomicity by using normalization might help

Comment: Using a LIKE that starts with a wildcard can make the query optimizer to ignore an index on that field. But long varchars are often not indexed, so a LIKE wouldn't make it slower on those. The query would benefit from an index on state though.

Comment: The OP stated he needs to search for hundreds of street names - didn't say anything about the size of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Text is good for that.

*Super* basic example:

```
CREATE INDEX test_idx_addr ON address_table (full_address)
indextype is ctxsys.context;

select * from address_table
where contains(full_address,'MOJAVE RD') > 0;
```

But there's a lot to it, so read up on it well if you decide to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I like the Oracle Text solution best. On the other hand:

If you're after a simple solution using an ordinary index, you could try a covering index and force a plan that does an index full scan. **This is just a suggestion to try and not intended to be a good solution for all cases.**

Firstly, I'd check the plan the query is currently using. If it's using a full table scan, and this is taking too long, you could try the following approach:

For example, put an index on just `(state, full_address)`, then check the explain plan for the query. If it does a full scan on the new index, followed by a table access by Rowid, then it's done it's job.

If the plan hasn't automatically picked up the index (i.e. it's still doing a FTS), you could force its hand with something like this:

```
SELECT
  a.full_address,
  a.city,
  a.state,
  a.zip
FROM
  address_table a
WHERE a.rowid in (
  select a1.rowid from address_table a1
  where  a1.full_address LIKE '%MOJAVE RD%'
  AND   a1.state IN ('NV')
);
```

There are probably other ways of achieving the same effect. The idea is to get it to do the quickest scan possible over the index for matching rows, and only then to get the rest of the data needed from the table.

**NOTE** however, that the performance of this plan *could very well be worse* than your current situation - especially if there is a reasonably large volume of matching records in the table.

Of course, if you can change your requirements to only retrieve the `state` and `full_address` columns, this will be even faster (since you can avoid accessing the table entirely).